# Spell check in TeXworks

Tags: texworks, spelling

I am using TeXworks and I would like to enable spell check in my language (Slovak). I downloaded the corresponding .dic and .aff files, put them in the .../resources/dictionaries folder but when I open up TeXworks the spelling is empty, there is no language, not even English, not even when I open up preferences. I have the .dic and .aff files also in the .../myspell/dicts folder together with the English ones but TeXworks still doesn't recognize them.

Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu.